# CountIf formula mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, countif

Can you help me with a `COUNTIF` formula?

I have these conditions - as if I were applying a filter:

- In Col K, select `Tablet` and `NA`
- In Col I, select `<>Duplicate TT` (i.e select everything expect Duplicate TT)
- In Col G, select `Yes`

I'm using the below formula but getting the wrong count:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
[AH124] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "Tablet", .Range("K:K"), "NA") + wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT") + wf.CountIf(.Range("G:G"), "Yes")

End With
```

Comment: you have `CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "Tablet", .Range("K:K"), "NA")` ? how can a certain cell equal both "Tablet" and "NA" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first clause is the issue because no value in column K will be both `Tablet` and `NA` at the same time:

```
wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "Tablet", .Range("K:K"), "NA")
```

So you need to re-arrange the formula:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
    [AH124] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "Tablet", .Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", .Range("G:G"), "Yes") +  _
        wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "NA", .Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", .Range("G:G"), "Yes")

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
    [AH124] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "=Tablet", .Range("K:K"), "=NA") + _
                wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT") + _
                wf.CountIf(.Range("G:G"), "=Yes")
End With
```

I've added `=` in your tests, because without it it'll count all cells **containing** Tablet, NA, Yes, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT"` is going to pick all the blanks all the way to the bottom of the sheet so you should restrict the range to the bottom row: `Range("I2:I & Range("I" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), "<>Duplicate TT"` (this assumes you're stating to the check on the second row because of headers) and you should probably do that for the rest of your formula too